# .NET WebService JSON date in ISO-8601 format

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, json, web-services

I am calling a .net asmx webservice that returns a number of fields. One of the fields in a date. The date is in the format of: `"effective_date":"\/Date(978411600000)\/"`

According to this SO question: [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/format-a-microsoft-json-date) it would be better if the date returned was in ISO 8601 format, this way JavaScript would be able to interpret it as a date.

Currently I use the following javascript: `new Date(d.effective_date)` and I get the message `Invalid Date`. According to the linked SO question I should be able to do this if I can get the web service to pass the date in ISO format rather than in `\/Date(978411600000)\/` format.

My question is, how do I get the webservice to return the date in ISO 8601 format?

**Note:**
I'm aware that I can use this (per the answer from the linked question): `var date = new Date(parseInt(d.effective_date.substr(6)));`, however it is mentioned in a comment that `Incoming date values should be formatted in ISO-8601`, so I'm wondering how to get the incoming date from the web service to be in this ISO format.

Comment: How is your web service? what are you using, asp.net, mvc, etc.? If you used `Json.Net`, you could use `DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat`

Comment: I'm using asp.net; I updated the tags to reflect.

Comment: @kralco626 did you find the solution? I am also experiencing the same issue and would like asmx web service to return the date in ISO-8601 format! I know I can add javascript code to make date compatible but would prefer that web service returns all dates in ISO-8601 format.

Comment: p.s. I am using .net 4.

Answer (score -1):

You may use:

```
var date = new Date(d.effective_date);
date.toISOString(); // ISO-8601 formatted string
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nanndoj/gjtkvrsy/

Comment: that is on the JavaScript side correct? I want to pass the date from the web service to javascript in ISO format. Right now, if I say new Date(d.effective_date) javascript gives me an Invalid Date message because the date sent from the web service is not formatted correctly.

Comment: I guess you are getting invalid date because your server is returning the data prefixed by a "Date(" string. You may remove this or eval("new " + d.effective_date) instead of put it as a new Date() argument

Comment: ya, I could do a substring on that string to remove the date and then parse the int as shown in the answer on the question I linked to. However, there is a way to get the web service to return the string in ISO format, which is preferred. I'm trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: How does this post answer this: *"so I'm wondering how to get the incoming date from the web service to be in this ISO format"* ?

Comment: In all fairness I added the note in after this post, but it doesn't answer the question: `My question is, how do I get the webservice to return the date in ISO 8601 format?` which was there originally